# Floating Point Math Execution Time

Tags: c++, floating-point, x86

What accounts for the added execution time of the first data set?  The assembly instructions are the same.

With DN_FLUSH flag not on, the first data set takes 63 milliseconds, the second set takes 15 milliseconds.
With DN_FLUSH flag on, the first data set takes 15 milliseconds, the second set takes ~0 milliseconds.

Therefore, in both cases the execution time of the first data set is much greater.

Is there any way to decrease the execution time to be closer in line with the second data set?

I am using C++ Visual Studio 2005, /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast running on Intel Core 2 Duo T7700 @ 2.4Ghz Windows XP Pro.

```
#define NUMLOOPS 1000000

// Denormal values flushed to zero by hardware on ALPHA and x86
// processors with SSE2 support. Ignored on other x86 platforms
// Setting this decreases execution time from 63 milliseconds to 16 millisecond
// _controlfp(_DN_FLUSH, _MCW_DN);

float denormal = 1.0e-38;
float denormalTwo = 1.0e-39;
float denormalThree = 1;

tickStart = GetTickCount();

// Run First Calculation Loop 
for (loops=0; loops < NUMLOOPS; loops++)
{
    denormalThree = denormal - denormalTwo;
}

// Get execution time
duration = GetTickCount()-tickStart;
printf("Duration = %dms\n", duration);

float normal = 1.0e-10;
float normalTwo = 1.0e-2;
float normalThree = 1;

tickStart = GetTickCount();

// Run Second Calculation Loop 
for (loops=0; loops < NUMLOOPS; loops++)
{
    normalThree = normal - normalTwo;
}

// Get execution time
duration = GetTickCount()-tickStart;
printf("Duration = %dms\n", duration);
```

Comment: You should be aware that GetTickCount() is nearly worthless for timing code.  It's granularity tends to be very large, perhaps as large as 100 ms, varying from system to system.  Use QueryPerformanceCounter() instead.

Comment: QueryPerformanceCounter() is a pain to use... try timeGetTime(). Also, GetTickCount() isn't that bad for things that run several seconds or more - just be aware of the accuracy.

Comment: BTW, don't assume that using /arch:SSE2 /fp:fast actually make your code faster. For my codes, I have found that /fp:precise and using the FP stack is actually faster. Similarly, don't assume floats are faster than doubles. Test all options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting from Intel's optimization manual:

> When an input operand for a SIMD
>   floating-point instruction [here this includes scalar arithmetic done using SSE] contains
>   values that are less than the
>   representable range of the data type,
>   a denormal exception occurs. This
>   causes a significant performance
>   penalty. An SIMD floating-point
>   operation has a flush-to-zero mode in
>   which the results will not underflow.
>   Therefore subsequent computation will
>   not face the performance penalty of
>   handling denormal input operands.

As for how to avoid this, if you can't flush denormals: do what you can to make sure your data is scaled appropriately and you don't encounter denormals in the first place.  Usually this means delaying applying some scale factor until you've finished all of your other computation.

Alternatively, do your computations in `double` which has a much larger exponent range, and therefore makes it much less likely that you will encounter denormals in the first place.

Comment: By the way, the denormal limit of `float` is roughly 1.18e-38 and that of `double` is roughly 2.225e-308.

Comment: @KennyTM: Use base 2 and avoid the approximations: float underflows at `2**-126`, double at `2**-1022`

Answer (score 2):

Another quote from the Intel manuals, volume 1, chapter 10.2.3.3:

The flush-to-zero mode is not compatible with IEEE Standard 754. The IEEE mandated
masked response to underflow is to deliver the denormalized result (see
Section 4.8.3.2, “Normalized and Denormalized Finite Numbers”). The flush-to-zero
mode is provided primarily for **performance reasons**. At the cost of a slight precision
loss, faster execution can be achieved for applications where underflows are common
and rounding the underflow result to zero can be tolerated.