# Why does the speed of this SOR solver depend on the input?

Tags: c++, optimization, floating-point, sparse-matrix

Related to my [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2388196/how-to-speed-up-my-sparse-matrix-solver), I have now modified the sparse matrix solver to use the SOR (Successive Over-Relaxation) method. The code is now as follows:

```
void SORSolver::step() {
    float const omega = 1.0f;
    float const
        *b = &d_b(1, 1),
        *w = &d_w(1, 1), *e = &d_e(1, 1), *s = &d_s(1, 1), *n = &d_n(1, 1),
        *xw = &d_x(0, 1), *xe = &d_x(2, 1), *xs = &d_x(1, 0), *xn = &d_x(1, 2);
    float *xc = &d_x(1, 1);
    for (size_t y = 1; y < d_ny - 1; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 1; x < d_nx - 1; ++x) {
            float diff = *b
                - *xc
                - *e * *xe
                - *s * *xs - *n * *xn
                - *w * *xw;
            *xc += omega * diff;
            ++b;
            ++w; ++e; ++s; ++n;
            ++xw; ++xe; ++xs; ++xn;
            ++xc;
        }
        b += 2;
        w += 2; e += 2; s += 2; n += 2;
        xw += 2; xe += 2; xs += 2; xn += 2;
        xc += 2;
    }
}
```

Now the weird thing is: if I increase `omega` (the relaxation factor), the execution speed starts to depend *dramatically* on the values inside the various arrays!

For `omega = 1.0f`, the execution time is more or less constant. For `omega = 1.8`, the first time, it will typically take, say, 5 milliseconds to execute this `step()` 10 times, but this will gradually increase to nearly 100 ms during the simulation. If I set `omega = 1.0001f`, I see an accordingly slight increase in execution time; the higher `omega` goes, the faster execution time will increase during the simulation.

Since all this is embedded inside the fluid solver, it's hard to come up with a standalone example. But I have saved the initial state and rerun the solver on that state every time step, as well as solving for the actual time step. For the initial state it was fast, for the subsequent time steps incrementally slower. Since all else is equal, that proves that the execution speed of this code is dependent on the values in those six arrays.

This is reproducible on Ubuntu with g++, as well as on 64-bit Windows 7 when compiling for 32-bits with VS2008.

I heard that NaN and Inf values can be slower for floating point calculations, but no NaNs or Infs are present. Is it possible that the speed of float computations otherwise depends on the values of the input numbers?

Comment: Are you sure you do not measure some other codepaths that depend on the values of the calculations?

Comment: If you continue to have performance issues, consider using a GPU for these calculations.  GPU's are very good at sparse matrix work.

Comment: @ebo: I used the real-time clock in Linux to measure just this call. So yes, I'm quite sure.

Comment: @Mark: I know, but that limits the number of platforms that I can run this on. I will run it on the GPU as a last resort if need be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer to your last question is "yes" - denormalized (very close to zero) numbers require special handling and can be much slower. My guess is that they're creeping into the simulation as time goes on. See this related SO post: [Floating Point Math Execution Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051534/floating-point-math-execution-time)

Setting the floating-point control to flush denormals to zero should take care of things with a negligible imapct on the simulation quality.

Comment: Denormalized values are indeed getting into it; I'm solving for the fluid pressure to get the divergence (`d_b` above) as close to zero as possible. So this explains it, and you once more have taught me something. Many thanks! (Your confusion about `1-omega` is probably because the matrix rows are scaled so there are `1`s on the diagonal. The `- *xc` does not come from there, but is actually the term `-omega * *xc` in your line of code. I'm getting reasonable answers.)

Comment: Glad that did the trick. I heard a horror story from a coworker recently - right before a big trade show a few years ago, the demo program was slowing to a crawl after running for a few minutes. It turned out a bug in the graphics driver wasn't resetting the floating-point control flag properly, and they were getting denormals from repeated multiplication of a damping factor in the rigid body simulation. Simple enough to fix once they knew the problem, but took them a day or two of debugging to track it down. Anyway, I immediately thought of that when I read your description.

Answer (score 0):

[celion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392932/why-does-the-speed-of-this-sor-solver-depend-on-the-input/2393038#2393038) turns out to be the correct one. The post he links to says to turn on flush-to-zero of denormalized values:

```
#include <float.h>
_controlfp(_MCW_DN, _DN_FLUSH);
```

However, this is Windows-only. Using gcc on Linux, I did the same thing with a whiff of inline assembly:

```
int mxcsr;
__asm__("stmxcsr %0" : "=m"(mxcsr) : :);
mxcsr |= (1 << 15); // set bit 15: flush-to-zero mode
__asm__("ldmxcsr %0" : : "m"(mxcsr) :);
```

This is my first x86 assembly ever, so it can probably be improved. But it does the trick for me.

Comment: You can set the FP environment portably with fenv.h (C99).

Comment: This is C++, so that won't work directly. But it might be possible to steal that implementation. Thanks!