# How do I see if my compiler have FTZ and DMZ flag enabled?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm not really able with compiler/sse, but for some purpose I need to check if the denormals numbers are deactivated (for optimizing performances).

How do I check if my compiler has those flags (`FTZ` and `DMZ`) on/off? I'm on Visual Studio 2015 and Windows 10 Professional.

Theoretically is in the `x86intrin.h`? I can't find it.

**EDIT**

Within `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\linkopts\loosefpmath.cpp` I have this code:

```
//
// loosefpmath.cpp
//
//      Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//
// A link option that sets the DAZ and FTZ bits for SSE2 architectures.
//
#include <float.h>



extern "C" void __CRTDECL _initialize_denormal_control()
{
    _controlfp_s(nullptr, _DN_FLUSH, _MCW_DN);
}
```

Comment: Have a read of (and parents of): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8b5ts9s(v=vs.100).aspx says in header `xmmintrin.h`  Note that  the FPU state is per thread.

Comment: Your compiler doesn't control those bits.  You can see the code you want in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\crt\src\linkopts\loosefpmath.cpp

Comment: @HansPassant: edited the answer! Check the code! Are denormals value ignored  with that settings?

Comment: Well, not ignored, the point is to get them truncated to 0.  Try it.

Comment: For an explanation of `_DN_FLUSH` see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2051534/floating-point-math-execution-time (you could find this easily with a Google search).

Comment: @HansPassant: yes, what I mean! The question is: whit my actual settings, is compiler already truncate them to 0? Or need I to add further flags?

Comment: As noted, no, the compiler does not control this.  You have to call _controlfp_s() like that yourself before you do the math that needs to be "fast".  I do recommend you restore it afterwards, tinkering with this processor register can be destabilizing to math code in a library that was tested with normal settings.  Albeit that FTZ is fairly innocent.  Fwiw, you found this code in the CRT source directory only because it is used in UWP apps.